# ios facebook login - Could not connect to the server

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, sdk, facebook-login

I use default Hello Facebook Sample.

Hello Facebook Sample project is default, without any changes.

I run app, and when I try to login in Facebook, I get error:

```
> FBLoginView encountered an error=Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5
> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)"
> UserInfo=0x1ed594f0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error
> Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."
> UserInfo=0x1ed4b690
> {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me?sdk=ios&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20130409&format=json&access_token=BAAFDDRlIT2wBAGKjngoxZCh3nkTWrfQjvO6ZASvctCGIyEg1h4gUA7n4zIIwd9iYZAWrRLkxEpVZB5SjHasSGbFll8aQGi42DGSxmjjvUxpbORWKNuYTaJwWSETLUSmmR6gZCG2FVFdJqorFbWZBxJwewfVpM1Ns4XwisSz4qQwdjKuWKaZATuOnzaYnyhWYMyp71zSMkXbUa8WGBLTovti5aWTZBckDlNZCTEtT5GKhie6eSgMEbjYDs,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me?sdk=ios&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20130409&format=json&access_token=BAAFDDRlIT2wBAGKjngoxZCh3nkTWrfQjvO6ZASvctCGIyEg1h4gUA7n4zIIwd9iYZAWrRLkxEpVZB5SjHasSGbFll8aQGi42DGSxmjjvUxpbORWKNuYTaJwWSETLUSmmR6gZCG2FVFdJqorFbWZBxJwewfVpM1Ns4XwisSz4qQwdjKuWKaZATuOnzaYnyhWYMyp71zSMkXbUa8WGBLTovti5aWTZBckDlNZCTEtT5GKhie6eSgMEbjYDs,
> NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x1ed57120 "Could not connect to the server."},
> com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200,
> com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1ede3c90, state:
> FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x1ede3070, appID: 355198514515820,
> urlSchemeSuffix: ,
> tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1ede9990>,
> expirationDate: 2013-06-30 13:37:41 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-05-01
> 14:24:53 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000,
> permissions:( )>}
```

**What is the reason of problem?**

I tried to use different versions of Facebook SDK (3.5.1, 3.5, 3.2.1)

I use iPod Touch 4g with iOS 6.1

**Notice:** I seem this problem occurred after bug with Infinite Loop when calling requestNewPublishPermissions: in SDK 3.5 https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/188127071335876
Because when I try to login 2 weeks ago, everything was OK.

Comment: Are you logging in via the web, the Facebook app, or the builtin settings?

Comment: I tried each of these three ways

Comment: and the problem remains

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the HelloFacebookSample app from SDK 3.2.1 and it is working well for me. It looks like you are having some sort of network problem, but who knows? Here are some suggestions:

- can you ping graph.facebook.com?
- Have you tried again? Maybe they had a temporary server problem.
- Do you have this problem with other sample apps?
- Are you able to get to Facebook from outside the sample app, just by going to Safari  on your device or Facebook app?
- Have you tried with a different Facebook account?
- Does the sample app run on your simulator?
- Are you sure you did not modify the app at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Settings -> Facebook -> YourAppName` in order to allow your app to use the facebook account. In this case, I display an alert asking the user to turn the switch on for the app.